# Octave Can't fill matrix in loop

Tags: matlab, loops, octave

I am basic in Octave, could someone help me with my code?

```
A = zeros(40);
format long
function xn=xnf(n,xn,c)
    if n<=40
        xn = xn^2+c;
        A(n,n)=xn;
        n++;
        xnf(n,xn,c);
    end
end
xnf(1,2,-2)
```

I want to add xn value into matrix, but it always has ony zero values - why?

Comment: You should consider using for-loops instead of recoursion in such cases. Your code is really confusing.

Comment: The reason it has only zeros is because you do not pass `A` into your function. Thus the line `A(n,n)=xn;` in your function actually creates a new variable called `A` that is scoped to the function, as soon as you exit the function (or enter into the next recursive call) that `A` fall out of scope. @mhmsa's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For the values you have specified (`n=1`, `xn=2`, `c=-2`) the matrix you will get is 2's along the main diagonal and zeros everywhere else, which can be made with `A=diag(2*ones(40,1))`.

If you want to change the parameters, this code will work in Matlab, and hence should work in octave:

```
N=40;
V=zeros(1,N);
V(1)=xn;
for i=2:N
    V(i)=V(i-1)^2+c;
end
A=diag(V);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about Octave but in matlab if i want the the value xn to be added to the Matrix A and what i want is the matrix then i would do it like that

```
function A=xnf(n,xn,c,A)
   if n<=40
       xn = xn^2+c;
       A(n,n)=xn;
       n=n+1;
       A=xnf(n,xn,c,A);
   end
end
```

because all of the variables used inside the function are deleted once you return so if you need The A matrix make sure you return it

Comment: Think the recoursive call should be 'A=xnf(n,xn,c);' in this case